# IOS 8.0.2 Facebook launch issues - it wont launch!

Tags: ios, facebook

my facebook wont even open now the update has happended! it flashes open for a nano-second and then automatically closes again. should I also try the delete and re download?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the app and reinstalling the latest version from the app store.